# How to add a partial view inside a DevExpress navbar

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, devexpress

I have a DevExpress navbar that I want to display a partial view inside of but when I try to add a partial view it displays the partial outside of the navbar.

```
        @Html.DevExpress().NavBar(
        settings =>
        {
            settings.Name = "navBarSettings";
            settings.Groups.Add(group => {
                group.Text = "Miscellaneous Properties";
                Html.RenderPartial("MiscellaneousPropertiesPartialView");
            });
            settings.Groups.Add(group =>
            {
                group.Text = "Other Properties";
            });
        }).GetHtml()
```

The screen displays like this
[image: Devexpress Navbar with partial view]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Html.DevExpress().NavBar(
            settings =>
            {
                settings.Name = "navBarSettings";
                settings.Groups.Add(group => {
                    group.Text = "Miscellaneous Properties";
                    group.SetContentTemplateContent(c =>
                        {
                            Html.RenderPartial("MiscellaneousPropertiesPartialView");
                        }
                    );
                });

                settings.Groups.Add(group =>
                {
                    group.Text = "Other Properties";
                });

            }).GetHtml()     
    }
```